# How to display html page kept on sdcard on webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I am not able to display html page kept in sdcard on webview. I have tried using this two methods:

```
webPage.loadUrl("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/page1.html");
```

and

```
webPage.loadUrl("content://com.android.htmlfileprovider"+
   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/page1.html");
```

Please Guide.

Comment: have u set permission in android manifest

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

Comment: @TheMechanic I have added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> and <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>.
My issue has been solve. Thanks for help.

Comment: hey friend just vote a point for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This.

```
webPage.loadUrl("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/page1.html");
```

**You forgot to add slash.**

Add Internet Permission and Read External Permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Sorry in formatting question i forgot to add slash, but i used it in my program.

Comment: have you add internet permission ?

Comment: Thanks...I missed the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>. Its working fine now.